# Custom Validator - Marcar form como no válido

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Estoy realizando una validación personalizada para los formularios de mi aplicación. Basada en angular 7.

Para ello, he creado una directiva personalizada, La cual lanza una serie de validaciones a partir de diferentes criterios, de la manera que sigue. Por ejemplo, la validación de un campo CIF.

```
 cif(cif: any) {

    const regexp: RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z]([0-9]{7})([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])$/;

    if (cif != null) {
      if(regexp.test(cif)){


      let numero: string = cif.substr(1, 7);
      let control: string = cif.substr(cif.length - 1, 1);

      let suma1 = 0;
      let suma2 = 0;
      let n: number;

      for (let i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
        n = parseInt(numero[i], 10);
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          n *= 2;
          suma2 += n < 10 ? n : n - 9;
        } else {
          suma1 += n;
        }
      }

      let control_num: number =
        10 - Number((suma1 + suma2).toString().substr(-1));
      let control_letr: string = 'JABCDEFGHI'.substr(control_num, 1);

      if (control !== control_num.toString() && control !== control_letr) {
        this.addInvalid();
      } else {
        this.addValid();
      }
    } else {
      this.addInvalid();
    }
    } else {
      this.reset();
    }
  }
```

Cuando esa validación no es correcta, marco el `input` con una `class invalid`.

```
      addInvalid() {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'valid', false);
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'invalid', true);
  }
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto, pero me gustaría marcar el `form` que contiene el `input` el cual estoy validando como `invalid` en el `validator` propio de la etiqueta `form` que tiene javascript. ¿Alguien sabe como realizarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberias añadirle un error al `input`, si estas usando reactive Forms, podrías hacer esto:

```
formGroup.get('CIF').setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

y para quitarle el error

```
formGroup.get('CIF').setErrors(null);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.